# The sequence $(\frac {\sin nx}{ \sqrt{n}})$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, real-numbers

> Show that the sequence $(\frac {\sin nx}{ \sqrt{n}})$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$.

$|\sin nx / \sqrt{n}| \leq |1/ \sqrt{n}|$  $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ since $|\sin nx| \leq 1$.

Let us choose $n>1/\epsilon^2 > 0$ $\implies$ $\epsilon  > 1/\sqrt{n}$.

Then for a given $\epsilon > 0$,

$|\sin nx / \sqrt{n}| \leq |1/ \sqrt{n}|   <  \epsilon$ $\forall  x  \in  \mathbb R$.

Hence, it is uniformly convergent to $0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb R$.

I don't know whether I am right or wrong, please suggest.

Comment: You have shown the sequence converges, though personally I might have said "then for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $n>N = \lceil 1/\epsilon^2\rceil$ ...".  You might tell us what is the additional property of  *uniform convergence* for a sequence of numbers rather than a sequence of functions

Comment: Sorry didn't understand ,what else to show

Comment: What makes a convergent sequence *uniformly* convergent?

Comment: I'd personally just write $\sup_x |\sin(nx)/\sqrt{n}| \leq 1/\sqrt{n}\to 0$.